# how to post from flash abject action script to wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, flash, posts

I am trying to post(upload) an image file to Wordpress from within a flash object embedded inside one of the pages of Wordpress. I get a fatal error like this:

**Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function wp_insert_post() in **/home/content/94/11856294/html/wp-content/themes/notoriouswordpress/test.php** on line **35**
.

It looks like the Wordpress functions are not available to call from inside the flash object action script which calls the test.php file to insert the post. How do I get access to the Worpress functions inside flash object action script calling to the test.php to post an image into the Media of Wordpress? Any help would be appreciated...Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for front end uploader function

Is this plugin worked for you http://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-uploader/installation/

?

If need to convert it into flash, just tweak/develop it. Be sure to test it first.